# SQL server Query to get result after calculation

Tags: t-sql

Below is the code

```
create table #temp(nm varchar(10))

insert into #temp values ('1+2')
insert into #temp values ('(1+2)*3')

select * from #temp
```

I need the result as the mathematical calculation answers

The result should be 3 in the first row and 9 in the second row. can you guide me with a query for the same

Comment: First, if you want the result of the query to be a result of your calculation (a number) then the datatype of the **nm** column should reflect that. Second, the quotes around your numbers are declaring that they are strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Sever does not support macro substitution, nor does it have an EVAL() function.  This leaves Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,nm varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'1+2')
,(2,'(1+2)*3')
,(3,'datediff(DAY,''2018-01-01'',getdate())')  -- Added Just for Fun


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + concat('(',ID,',',nm,')')
                                     From @YourTable  A
                                     For XML Path (''))
                                 ,1,1,'')
Exec('Select * from (values ' + @SQL + ')A([ID],[Value])')
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value
1   3
2   9
3   1099
```